# label array in an panel

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d, multidimensional-array

I need to make a 6x6 grid for a game, yet none of the labels seem to work,

it might be something small.

```
Label[][] map = new Label[6][];
for (int i = 0;i < columns;i++)
{
    map[i] = new Label[6];
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        map[i][j] = new Label();
        map[i][j].AutoSize = true;
        map[i][j].BackColor = Color.Black;
        map[i][j].Location = new Point(i * spacing, j * spacing);
        map[i][j].Name = "map" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString();
        map[i][j].Width = spacing;
        map[i][j].Height = spacing;
        map[i][j].TabIndex = 0;
        map[i][j].Text = "test" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
        panel1.Controls.Add(map[i][j]);
    }
    this.Controls.AddRange(map[i]);
}
MessageBox.Show("greatsuscces");
return;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "none (...) seem to work"? What happens, and what are you expecting?

Comment: Define `none [...] seem to work`. Do you get an error message, or unexpected behaviour, or something else? Also, where is `columns` defined and set?

Comment: What about setting visibility? What is not working? Where are you doing this? What technology?

Comment: so what I want to make is that i get a 6x6/9x9/12x12 grid for a game called stratego and each label wil contain a text and a tag wich will be set, what i see is simply nothing. maybe panel1 doesnt work with this?
it's in c#

Comment: @Kapein: Do you see `panel1`? (e.g. when you set its `BackColor` to something easily recognizeable)

Comment: From what I understand, `AddRange` takes a list of controls. For it to work, you will have to add all the labels to a single array (of 36 elements), each of its element will be a label.

Comment: @Kapein you're obviously doing this in winforms. Please consider [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367126/console-application-code-to-windows-form-c-sharp#comment21713851_15367126)

Comment: @Kapein do you accept WPF-based solutions? you could integrate that in an existing winforms application using the `ElementHost`.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: The labels are already added with `panel1.Controls.Add` - I wonder why he/she adds them again directly to `this` afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `Panel` is large enough, first, maybe 500x500. Second, you need to add all of the labels to the `Panel` and not `this.Controls`

```
       int spacing = 75;
        int columns = 6;

        //Use your variable above to create the array
        Label[][] map = new Label[columns][];

        for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
            //Create a new sub array
            map[i] = new Label[columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                map[i][j] = new Label();
                map[i][j].AutoSize = true;
                map[i][j].BackColor = Color.Black;
                map[i][j].Location = new Point(i * spacing, j * spacing);
                map[i][j].Name = "map" + i.ToString() + "," + j.ToString();
                map[i][j].Width = spacing;
                map[i][j].Height = spacing;
                map[i][j].TabIndex = 0;
                map[i][j].Text = "test" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
            }
            //Add the range to the panel
            panel1.Controls.AddRange(map[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you alot sir!
I didn't notice the this.controls!